# Check current time (without date) is between two times in C

Tags: c, time

Can you help me to implement this in C :

```
 ((on_time <= off_time and CURTIME() >= on_time and CURTIME() <= off_time) or
 (off_time < on_time and (CURTIME() <= off_time or CURTIME() >= on_time))
```

I have `on_time = 18:00:00` and `off_time = 01:00:00` (next day after midnight). I want to check if `current time : 19:27:00` is between on and off_time. On and off_time are strings.

Thanks

Comment: If `off_time = 01:00:00` is the next day, how do you set `off_time` to 1:00 this morning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shortest comparison solution consists to convert all string-timestamp to time_t value.

> Improving the source as Brian McFarland suggests `memset()`.

```
struct tm tmVar;
time_t t_on_time, t_off_time, t_curr_time;

    memset(&tmVar, 0, sizeof(tmVar));    
    if(sscanf(on_time, "%d:%d:%d", &tmVar.tm_hour,  &tmVar.tm_min,  &tmVar.tm_sec)==3) {
        t_on_time = mktime(&tmVar);
    }
    memset(&tmVar, 0, sizeof(tmVar)); 
    if(sscanf(off_time, "%d:%d:%d", &tmVar.tm_hour,  &tmVar.tm_min,  &tmVar.tm_sec)==3) {
        t_off_time = mktime(&tmVar);
    }
    memset(&tmVar, 0, sizeof(tmVar)); 
    if(sscanf(CURTIME(), "%d:%d:%d", &tmVar.tm_hour,  &tmVar.tm_min,  &tmVar.tm_sec)==3) {
        t_curr_time = mktime(&tmVar);
    }
```

And your comparison is:

```
if (((t_on_time <= t_off_time) && (t_curr_time >= t_on_time) && (t_curr_time <= t_off_time)) ||
 ((t_off_time < t_on_time) && ((t_curr_time <= t_off_time) || (t_curr_time >= t_on_time))) {
    // To do something
}
```

Comment: A few cautions about `mktime`: 1) it will return -1 if the `struct tm` cannot be converted to `time_t`, 2) it may manipulate the underlying `struct tm` to "normalize" it, and 3) if you don't `memset(&tmVar, 0, sizeof(tmVar))`, in before each scanf, you won't get what you expect (partially because of #2).

Answer (score 0):

I would use sscanf to convert the char buffers to ints and then compare those

Example:

```
int on_hour, on_minute, on_second;
int off_hour, off_minute, off_second;

sscanf(on_timestr, "%d:%d:%d", &on_hour, &on_minute, &on_second);
sscanf(off_timestr, "%d:%d:%d", &off_hour, &off_minute, &off_second);

if (on_hour < off_hour)
//do your compare logic
```

Or:

```
#include <time.h>

tm on_time, off_time;

sscanf(on_time, "%d:%d:%d", &on_time.tm_hour, &on_time.tm__min, &on_time.tm_sec);
sscanf(off_time, "%d:%d:%d", &off_time.tm_hour, &off_time.tm__min, &off_time.tm_sec);
```

Comment: Be prepared to sanity check if using any `<time.h>` manipulations (e.g. `mktime` on your on_time / off_time) in example #2.

Comment: I think that OP's problem is that off_time is actually 1am of the next day.